# Find items that have at least one item in array and doesn't have other than array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to make a complex mongo query and after hours of trial and only error I'm here to ask for help.

Giving the following documents:

```
{
    // Item 1
    name: 'Tranças Nordestinas',
    author: 'Daiane Rosa',
    ingredients: [
        'wheatFlour',
        'sugar',
        'butter',
        'bakingPowder',
        'eggs'
    ]
}

{
    // Item 2
    name: 'Brigadeiro de Churros',
    author: 'Cristine Russel',
    ingredients: [
        'sugar',
        'chocolate'
    ]
}

{
    // Item 3
    name: 'Chá Mate Gelado',
    author: 'Victor Onofre',
    ingredients: [
        'sugar',
        'water'
    ]
}

{
    // Item 4
    name: 'Macarrão Verde ao Molho',
    author: 'Victor Onofre',
    ingredients: [
        'greenPasta',
        'tomatoSauce',
        'butter'
    ]
}
```

If I query the array [ 'sugar', 'water' ], only the third item shoud be returned.

If I query the array [ 'water', 'chocolate', 'wheatFlour', 'sugar', 'butter', 'bakingPowder', 'eggs' ], items 1, 2 and 3 should be returned.

And If I query the array [ 'sugar' ], no item should be returned.

Couldn't find a way to do this kind of query.
Don't know if mongodb is the right choise to do this query, would mysql perform better in this situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$redact` with `$setIsSubset` for your query.

`$setSubset` to compare the ingredients arrays with input array and return `true` when the ingredients array is a subset of the input array, which includes equals  too and `$redact` will use the result from above comparison; `true` value to keep and `false` value to remove the document.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [{
        $redact: {
            $cond: {
                if: {
                    $setIsSubset: ["$ingredients", ['sugar']]
                },
                then: "$$KEEP",
                else: "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }
    }]
);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much!